# .off(), .undelegate(), .unbind() event only from copied element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using

```
$(document).on('click', '.mySelector', function () {
    //do something
});
```

To delegate events to buttons.
Next I'm using `.clone(true)` to copy `div` which containing few buttons with delegated in to it events.
My question is how do I remove events form selected new created buttons?
I'm tried:

```
$(document).unbind('click', $(myNewDiv).find('.mySelector'));
```

Somehow it's removing events from all `$('.mySelector')` in whole document not only from this inside 'myNewDiv' object.

I have seen documentation of jQuery `.off()` and `.undelegate()` and they accept only string like selector (my div can't have any unique ID).

Is any option to remove events from selected elements inside jQuery object when they are delegated to document?

Comment: Sorry my bad, in code is `clone(true)`

Comment: Anyway probably your previous comment was helpful, because if its bound to all selectors inside element, when I will change selector of this element it should stop triggering this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click',  '.mySelector', function(){
   //do something
});
```

the code above means, "attach a click handler to the document, so whenever any element that corresponds to the '.mySelector' selector is clicked, fire the handler".

whenever you clone an element, you clone its class as well, therefore it will suit the '.mySelector' too.

the handler that you have delegated is attached to the document and not to the elmenets themselves. in order for the new elements to not fire the handler, you must make them not fit the selector. so either change their class to '.mySelector2' after cloning, or whatever.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a class to your clones:

```
var $clone = $original.clone(true).addClass("clone");
```

And reject that class in your delegated handler:

```
$(document).on("click", ".mySelector:not(.clone)", function() {
    // Do something...
});
```